# Сверстать таблицу при помощи div

Tags: css, табличная-верстка

Сделать предоставленную таблицу блочными элементами , с применением свойства CSS `display: table | table-row | table-cell`.

Пользоваться html запрещено.

[image: Таблица Менделеева]

Comment: сверстать без HTML? Это как?

Comment: Такое задание дали в академии, то есть нельзя пользоваться html тегами td, tr, th. Необходимо всё сделать свойствами CSS, а конкретно display: table | table-row | table-cell

Comment: просто используйте вместо `<table>` - `<div style="display:table">`, `<tr>` - `<div style="display:table-row">`, `<td>` - `<div style="display:table-cell">`

Comment: Это понятно, не подскажете как заменить свойство rowspan и colspan. Не могу понять как объединить ячейки, ведь div это блок, как не крути...

Comment: @Ahriman Наоборот, никаких ячеек объединять не надо. Каждый прямоугольник - это уже отдельный `div`. "Я академиев не кончал... Я их не закончил!" В.И. Чапаев

Comment: Вы меня совсем запутали, к чему тогда display: table | table-row | table-cell. Можно же ведь просто указать размеры div-ов и через position настроить их расположение. Или я чего то не понял ?

Comment: @ScreamingVoices а разве div - это не html? )))

Comment: html конечно, выразился не совсем точно, но суть вы уловили

Comment: @Ahriman *Это понятно, не подскажете как заменить свойство rowspan и colspan* - будет лучше если Вы в вопросе укажите, что именно Вам непонятно, а еще лучше если приведете пример Вашего кода(что уже получилось сделать).

Comment: позвольте полюбопвтствовать, что за академия с заданием из школьного курса?)))))))))) я год назад племяннику помогал с подобным заданием, он сейчас 7 классе

Comment: Получилось мало, была мысль сделать border:{none;} таким способом слить ячейки..table {
    display: table;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.borderbottom {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.bordertop {
    border-top: none;
}

.borderleft {
    border-left: none;
}

.borderright {
    border-right: none;
}

Comment: 2Air, академия шаг, первые уроки. Может и мне подскажите в какую сторону копать ?

Comment: а flex   тоже нельзя ?

Comment: flex к сожалению тоже нельзя (

Comment: верстка должна быть адаптивная?

Comment: Нет, нужно просто сделать таблицу

Comment: тогда флаг тебе в руки и вперед с песней...  position: absolute; и рисуй как душеньке твоей угодно...  работы на 10 мин

Comment: Можно маленький пример ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам пример, думаю он должен помочь.

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.d-table{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.d-tr{
  display: table-row;
}
.d-td{
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.d-td:not(.no-p){
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-table">
  <div class="d-tr">
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-tr">
    <div class="d-td no-p">
      <div class="d-table">
          <div class="d-tr">
            <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
          </div>
          <div class="d-tr">
            <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-td no-p">
      <div class="d-table">
          <div class="d-tr">
            <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
            <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
    <div class="d-td">lorem</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сергей, огромное спасибо, а тот тут люди пишут что задачка первый класс, а на выходе правильного ответа так и не дали. С абсолютной позиции и dispalay: table текст в ячейках начинает плыть.

Comment: @Ahriman тут и правда все элементарно, вы не должны тут использовать position: absolute;, как по мне суть этой задачи это понять как работают эти displya: table,table-row,table-cell...